# KONG API Gateway with Lumen / Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen, kong

I have some multi-tenant systems each built with laravel [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4/). These system serves in Different serves so that i Configured  KONG (API GateWay https://getkong.org/ ). Which is working fine for core PHP , but not for laravel.

This is the normal sample url for one of the lumen system.

```
http://139.59.60.229/lumen/public/index.php/profile
```

And this is the KONG url to access the same

```
http://139.59.60.229:8000/profile
```

Configurations and contention setting tested it's fine. 
please advice me a solution.

Comment: what's the wrong response and is there anything in error.log?

Comment: `NotFoundHttpException in RoutesRequests.php line 594:` 
no other errors

Comment: maybe there is something wrong in this api's config. so review your kong logs (default is in $kong/logs) to check if your api's upstream_url is right

Comment: Can you post your api config?